# How do I store entered data so it is available for the next time I run the program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm making a typing speed program, and I want someone to be able to add a passage if they want to the list of passages that are randomly chosen to type.

```
    passages.append(raw_input("Enter passage: "))
```

That is the code where people write the passage, but how can I save it to the dictionary so that when the program closes, it will still be there?

Answer (score 3):

To expand upon saving your dictionary directly into a file:

Use pickle to save and load from a file in python. (More details [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle))

```
#Save the dictionary
import pickle
pickle.dump( passages, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )

# Load the dictionary back from the pickle file.
import pickle

passages_loaded = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [shelve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) module to save it to a database-like file

Comment: -1: Actually according to the linked documentation, it's more of a persistent dictionary-like object, not a list like the OP wants to save. If you're proposing that it be made into something dictionary-like, putting a little effort into your might change my mind.

Comment: @martineau I think I misinterpreted the OP asking to save the "dictionary" to mean he had a `dict` or passages.  Woops.